# Can I specify a certain machine to be the driver in spark on yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

The question is exactly what is specified in the title.

I want to start my driver program on `192.168.1.1`, but the fact is when I submit my spark application to yarn, yarn will choose a random machine to be the driver of my application.

Can I choose the driver manually in yarn cluster mode?
the dupilicated question won't work on yarn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing driver to run on specific slave in spark standalone cluster running with "--deploy-mode cluster"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526723/forcing-driver-to-run-on-specific-slave-in-spark-standalone-cluster-running-with)

Comment: Not sure if it'll work on yarn but you can try the solution given above.

Comment: apparently,it's not working

Comment: I know the common answers to my question,thank you very much.I was wondering if there were some tricks can manage that?Or I won't ask here

Comment: Thinking aloud...I think the only way to do it would be to use YARN labels that I may have seen supported in Spark. By default, Spark on YARN would deploy the driver together with ApplicationMaster on a random machine (that meets the resource requirements)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thank u ~I will have a try

Answer (score 2):

Like Yaron replied before, with YARN as master you have two options:

- client
- cluster

If you select cluster mode then you let yarn manage where the driver is spawned, based on resource availability in Yarn. If you select client mode then the driver is spawned in the client process, on the server where you ran the spark-submit.

So, a solution for your problem should be to run the command
 `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client ...` 
on the machine you want the driver to be on.
Make sure that:

- the machine has the resources to host the driver,
- the resources you want to give to the driver are not committed to Yarn as well
- there is a Spark gateway (for CM) role on that machine

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use a specific machine as the driver, you should use `YARN Client mode`**

[SPARK docs - launching spark on yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#launching-spark-on-yarn):

> There are two deploy modes that can be used to launch Spark
>   applications on YARN. In cluster mode, the Spark driver runs inside an
>   application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster,
>   and the client can go away after initiating the application. In client
>   mode, the driver runs in the client process, and the application
>   master is only used for requesting resources from YARN.

In `YARN Client` mode - the driver runs in the client process (you can choose the driver machine, it is the machine which execute the spark-submit command)

In `YARN Cluster` mode -  the Spark driver runs inside an application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster.